# "httptrace" endpoint of Spring Boot Actuator doesn't exist anymore with Spring Boot 2.2.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

With Spring Boot 2.2.0 the "httptrace" Actuator endpoint doesn't exist anymore. How can I get this functionality back?

Comment: https://juplo.de/actuator-httptrace-does-not-work-with-spring-boot-2-2/

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The functionality has been [removed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2.0-M3-Release-Notes#actuator-http-trace-and-auditing-are-disabled-by-default) by default in Spring Boot 2.2.0.

As a workaround, add this configuration to the Spring environment:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: httptrace
```

and provide an `HttpTraceRepository` bean like this:

```java
@Configuration
// @Profile("actuator-endpoints")
// if you want: register bean only if profile is set
public class HttpTraceActuatorConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public HttpTraceRepository httpTraceRepository() {
        return new InMemoryHttpTraceRepository();
    }

}
```

http://localhost:8080/actuator/httptrace works again.

Comment: In my case @Profile annotation was unnecessary - after remove it its working !

Comment: can confirm the HttpTraceRepository is needed

Answer (score 7):

You need to enable httptrace by having following application properties. By default it is disabled

```
management.trace.http.enabled: true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: httptrace
```

and Requires an `HttpTraceRepository` bean. You can use Your own Custom implementation or `InMemoryHttpTraceRepository`

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately this is not right. At least not for Spring Boot 2.2.0 and above. See release notes  :)https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2.0-M3-Release-Notes#actuator-http-trace-and-auditing-are-disabled-by-default

Comment: What is not right, i have tested it with 2.2.2.RELEASE,  i found the information from documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints

Comment: Well... strange ..  according to the official 2.2.0 release notes one has to provide a bean and that's the only way I got it work (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes)

Comment: this worked for me. thanks ravthiru, missleading post comment by phip1611...

Comment: @FacundoLaxalde @ravthiru I have an update on this. `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: httptrace (or '*')` is definetly required, yes. But according to the release notes (and my own testing) `management.trace.http.enabled: true` is not required, although it can be used to disable this feature even if a HttpTraceRepository bean is present. Sorry for the circumstances!